# Stop Sticker Div at Element - Troubleshooting

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get a fixed div within a div to unstick once a certain element is reached. The desired outcome is shown at the link below.

http://www.pixelbind.com/make-a-div-stick-when-you-scroll/

I cannot get the unstick part to work correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var s = $("#sticker");
var pos = s.position(); 
var stickermax = $(document).outerHeight() - $("#nosticker").outerHeight() - s.outerHeight() - 40; //40 value is the total of the top and bottom margin
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    //s.html("Distance from top:" + pos.top + "<br />Scroll position: " + windowpos);
    if (windowpos >= pos.top && windowpos < stickermax) {
        s.attr("style", ""); //kill absolute positioning
        s.addClass("stick"); //stick it
    } else if (windowpos >= stickermax) {
        s.removeClass(); //un-stick
        s.css({position: "relative", top: stickermax + "px"}); //set sticker right above the footer

    } else {
        s.removeClass(); //top of page
    }
});
//alert(stickermax); //uncomment to show max sticker postition value on doc.ready
});
</script>
```

The site I'm working on is at http://iemajen.com/fosterpettit/

You can see the purchase form mid way down and get an idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried, `s.removeClass("stick");`

Comment: I did try that. I thought that maybe it was an issue with parent > child elements i.e. the sticky div was inside a separate parent div from where the unsticky div is. 

`<div>parent 1<div>child 1</div></div>-<div>parent 2<div>child 2</div></div>`

So I adjusted a few things in my code so the sticky and unsticky div are both children of the same parent.

I'm still facing the same problem. Once I scroll it sticks at the proper element but does not unstick at the unsticky...

[link](http://iemajen.com/fosterpettit/)

Comment: I managed to get this to work as desired. However, I'm a little confused about how this script actually works. Using the latest Chrome release, I notice each page refresh causes the script to behave differently i.e. one refresh works perfect, a second has div elements overlapping, and a third doesn't unstick at the place it first did, usually falling before the desired div.

I hope someone can help me wrap my head around this.